# pgfplotstabletypeset merged cells in middle of table

Tags: tables

I have to convert some `*.doc` files in LaTex and I have some hard work with converting some tables. I have, for example, tables like this:

[image: Merged cells]

and is **mandatory to import the values from `*.csv` file**. It's easy when I have the same number of columns on all the rows but I can't get to make it work for merged cells.

How could I do this? And how should the data in the `csv` file look?

P.S. I have to use `pgfplotstabletypeset`, but if not possible I can use other methodes.

Edit: the `cvs` file looks likes:

```
nr;ABC;test1;test2;test3;test4;test5

1;abc1;q;w;e;r;t

2;abc2;Test**;**;**;**;**

3;abc3;**;**;**;**;**;**

4;abc4;**;**;**;**;**;
```

and the cells with `**` should be merged. 
I don't know if this is possible ...

Comment: Is the structure of the table always the same (i.e. same number of rows and columns, and the same cells have to be merged)?

Comment: No. In other tables I have other cells merged. But it would be great to see and example exactly after my case from above. After that I will try to figure out what to do next.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include an example of your CSV files? Also, how do you want to specify which cells to merge?

Comment: This was one of my question: how the data in the cvs file should look? Meaning, how LaTex knows which cells should be merged?